# Celery ignored the parameter "queue" and sent message to all queues

Tags: python, celery

I use celery with redis as a broker.

I build out an add task and run two workers listen to different queues for testing.

```
celeryd -I tasks -l info -Q tasks
celeryd -I tasks -l info -Q count
```

Here is the tasks.py

```
from celery.task import task

@task(exchange="tasks")
def add(x, y):
    result = x + y
    return "I am queue 2.", result
```

However, no matter I assigned the queue or not, both queues run the task.

Please let me know if there is something I misunderstand. Thanks a lot.

The following is the celeryconfig.py

```
BROKER_URL = "redis://localhost:6379/0"

# Redis Backend
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis"
CELERY_REDIS_HOST = "localhost"
CELERY_REDIS_PORT = 6379
CELERY_REDIS_DB = 0
CELERY_SEND_EVENTS = True
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp"
CELERY_RESULT_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {"echo": True}

# CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = "default"
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE = "default"
CELERY_QUEUES = {
    "default": {
        "exchange": "default"
    },
    "tasks": {
        "exchange": "tasks"
    },
    "count": {
        "exchange": "tasks"
    }
}
```